# Given the polynomial $f = (X^2 + X + 1) ^ {40} + (X^2 - X + 1) ^ {40}$, find the coefficients of $f$ in its algebraic form.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Consider the polynomial:

$$f = (X^2 + X + 1) ^ {40} + (X^2 - X + 1)$$

with its algebraic form:

$$f = a_{80} X^ {80} + a_{79} X ^ {79} + ... + a_1 X + a_0$$

I have to find:

$$a_{15}$$

$$a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_{80}$$

$$a_0 + a_2 + a_4 + ... + a_{80}$$

I don't know how to solve this problem. This is what I tried:

Solving

$$X^2 + X + 1 = 0$$

I got:

$$x_1 = \dfrac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2} \hspace{2cm} x_2 = \dfrac{-1 + i \sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Solving

$$X^2 - X + 1 = 0$$

I got:

$$x_3 = \dfrac{1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2} = -x_1 \hspace{2cm} x_4 = \dfrac{1 - i\sqrt{3}}{2} = -x_2$$

So if I write my polynomial like this:

$$f = [ (X - x_1)(X - x_2) ] ^ {40} + [(X-x_3)(X-x_4)]^{40}$$

It is the same as:

$$f = (X-x_1)^{40}(X-x_2)^{40} + (X + x_1)^{40}(X+x_2)^{40}$$

But this is as far as I got. I don't see how I could use this to get the coefficients and solve the $3$ things that are asked.

Comment: Hint: what are the coefficients of terms with odd powers of $x$?

Comment: Hint: What's $f(1)$ in terms of the $a_i$s? What about $f(-1)$? What happens to the odd powers of $b$ when you use the binomial formula and expand
$(a+b)^{40}+(a-b)^{40}$?

Comment: Did you mean $f = (X^2 + X + 1) ^ {40} + (X^2 - X + 1)^{40}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the expression $f(x)=(x^2-x+1)^{40}+(x^2+x+1)^{40}$, you can see that

a)$f(x)=f(-x)\forall x\in\Bbb R$

b)$f(1)=3^{40}+1$

From $a)$, we get that $f$ is an even polynomial and hence, coefficients of all the odd powers of $x$ should be zero, in particular $a_{15}=0$.

From $b)$ we get that the sum of all the coefficients of $f$, which is same is the sum of all the coefficients of even powers of $x$ in $f(x)$ is $3^{40}+1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is even, $a_{15}=0$, and the second and third parts are both $f(1)=3^{40}+1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x) = (x^2 + x + 1) ^ {40} + (x^2 - x + 1) ^ {40}$$

$$f(X) = a_{80} X^ {80} + a_{79} X ^ {79} + ... + a_1 X + a_0$$

\begin{align}
   f(x) 
      &= (x^2 + x + 1) ^ {40} + (x^2 - x + 1) ^ {40} \\
      &= [(x^2+1) + x]^{40} + [(x^2+1)-x]^{40} \\
      &= \sum_{k=0}^{40} \binom{40}{k}\left[(x^2+1)^k x^{40-k} +
                                            (x^2+1)^k (-x)^{40-k}\right] \\
       &= 2\sum_{n=0}^{20} \binom{40}{2n}(x^2+1)^{2n} x^{40-2n}
\end{align}

So $f$ is an even function.

Thus

- $a_{15}=0$
- $a_0+a_1+a_2+\dots+a_{40} = a_0+a_2+a_4+\dots+a_{40} = f(1) = 3^{40}+1$